# Using VHOST for subdomains on Express

Tags: node.js, express, vhosts

I have 2 separated site (static web and application). I've tried to use `Express vhost` middleware but I couldn't manage.

For the below codes I configured my `hosts` file as;

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  process.localhost
```

my `server.js` codes

```
var connect = require('connect')
var express = require('express')
var vhost = require('vhost')
var app = require('./app')
var static = require('./static')

var server = connect()

server
.use(vhost('localhost', static.service))
.use(vhost('process.localhost', app.service))
.listen(1337, function(){
  console.log('Server is listening')
})
```

Then if I write my address bar *localhost:1337* static page comes this is good. However, if I write *process.localhost:1337* nothing comes.

What should I do?

**Edit**

If I add the below middleware to my codes when I write the address bar `localhost:1337` console write `localhost:1337` but is I write `process.localhost:1337` console write nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem was the change of hosts file permissions.

Solution is here;
https://serverfault.com/a/452269/277517